# how do I make my jquery ui tabs slide left and right?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow, jquery-ui-tabs

So I currently have a website with jQuery Ui tabs controlling the content.   I have previous and next buttons like so

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <div class="left-arrow">
      <a class="prev-tab" href="#"><img src="left-arrow.png"></a>
    </div>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    <div class="right-arrow">
      <a class="next-tab" href="#"><img src="right-arrow.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <div class="left-arrow">
      <a class="prev-tab" href="#"><img src="left-arrow.png"></a>
    </div>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    <div class="right-arrow">
      <a class="next-tab" href="#"><img src="right-arrow.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <div class="left-arrow">
      <a class="prev-tab" href="#"><img src="left-arrow.png"></a>
    </div>
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-arrow">
      <a class="next-tab" href="#"><img src="right-arrow.png"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript is like so:

```
var $tabs = $('#art-quiz').tabs();

$('.next-tab').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');

    $tabs.tabs("option", "active", ( selected+1 ) );

});

$('.prev-tab').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected') ;

    $tabs.tabs('select', ( selected - 1 ) );

});
```

I would like to slide the tab left if I click the prev-tab, and slide to the right if I click the next-tab.   The documentation doesn't give me a clear answer on how to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're talking about is changing the "hide" and "show" animations for the tabs depending on which button was clicked.

Here's [a jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AgFCu/) which uses the Javascript below.

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $tabs.tabs('option', 'hide', false);
        $tabs.tabs('option', 'show', false);
    }
});

$('.next-tab').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $tabs.tabs('option', 'hide', { effect: 'slide', direction: 'left', duration: 300 });
    $tabs.tabs('option', 'show', { effect: 'slide', direction: 'right', duration: 300 });
    var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'active');
    $tabs.tabs('option', 'active', (selected + 1));
});

$('.prev-tab').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $tabs.tabs('option', 'hide', { effect: 'slide', direction: 'right', duration: 300 });
    $tabs.tabs('option', 'show', { effect: 'slide', direction: 'left', duration: 300 });
    var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'active');
    $tabs.tabs('option', 'active', (selected - 1));
});
```

What it does is:

- When you click next-tab, slide the current tab left and the next tab in from the right.
- When you click prev-tab, slide the current tab right and the previous tab in from the left.
- Whenever a tab is activated, set hide and show back to default (false) so that clicking the tabs themselves doesn't do any kind of slide.

Comment: This is exactly it!  Thank you very much, could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo on jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6TEZ/489/)**

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
var selected;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next-tab').click(function(e){
     selected=$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
     selected++;
     $('#tabs').tabs('select', selected);
  });
  $('.prev-tab').click(function(e){
     selected=$('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
     selected--;
     $('#tabs').tabs('select', selected);
  });
});
```