# Slide current tab to the left and next tab in from right

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, slide

I've tried finding an answer to my question but without success.
I found this one for example: [jquery ui tabs slide left and right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663710/how-do-i-make-my-jquery-ui-tabs-slide-left-and-right/17665255#17665255) but it didn't do it for me.

I've got a working "tab section" with three tabs (you can see the code for that below).

What I want to achieve is to make the current tab slide to the left as you press the next tab which slide in from the right replacing the other one (and the opposite if you "go backwards" in the tabs).

See this great example: [See this tab effect](http://www.intersectioncapital.com/leadership.php).

My HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Daniel Pettersson</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Scott Asli</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Teamet</li>
</ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    background: #3b3b3b;
}
ul.tabs li {
    background: none;
    color: #b1b1b1;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
    color: #fff;
    background: url('images/tab-arrow.png') no-repeat 50% 100%;
}
.tab-content {
    display: none;
    background: transparent;
    padding: 30px 0;
    height:300px;
}
.tab-content.current { display: inherit; }
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })

})
```

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: I found this js code on the example page that has the effect I want:

```
//slide the button to the next item
function goNext() {
    if ( decount != counter) {
    $('#slider ul').animate({ left: '-=' + $('#slider').width() }, 400, 'swing', function() { });
    $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    decount++;
    window.location.hash = decount;
    }
}

function goBack() {
    if ( decount != 1) {
    $('#slider ul').animate({ left: '+=' + $('#slider').width() }, 400, 'swing', function() { });
    $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
    decount--;
    window.location.hash = decount;
    }
}
```

Could that be the solution? I'm not that good at jQuery so I don't know how to add it to the code I currently have..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Thanks @artdias90, but I'm completely new to jQuery and such so I don't understand anything on the link you suggested.

Could you create a sample code based on my code?

Comment: I played around a bit in JSFiddle but without success so far. Tried adding the jQuery code from the stackoverflow article I linked to in my question. You find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/s8zMy/ - please have a look and see what is wrong